# onclick event listener to li elements that passes this as parameter

Tags: javascript, html, list, onclick, addeventlistener

I have a list with a lot of p tags in it. Based on those p tags I will fill another div.
I passed this on by having `onclick="function(this)"` inside my li element.
Due to some changes I changed my code and I am now building my list using javascript.
But I don't know how to pass the onclick function to my list.

I tried using

```
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", function fillDiv(this);
document.getElementById("list").onclick = fillDiv(this);
```

and in javascript i tried

```
li.onclick = "fillDiv(this)";
```

My p tags get added to this list like this

```
p.innerHTML = obj.Name[i];
        li.appendChild(p);
```

Can't quite figure out how to pass on 'this' as a parameter because it's important to know what list element has been clicked.

Comment: How is the `<p>` you're attempting to reference related to the `#list`? Can you post more code so we can have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried event.target, event being the thing you pass to the function instead of this.

Comment: I put it in the edit @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for how you replace `onclick="function(this)"` with `addEventListener`, you do it like this:

```
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", fillDiv);
```

Within `fillDiv`, `this` will refer to the element you attached the click handler to. So `fillDiv` receives that as `this`, rather than as its first argument.

So:

```
function fillDiv() {
    // Use `this` where you used to use the first argument
}
```

You can also accept a parameter, because the function will be passed an argument containing the event, and on that object there's a `currentTarget` property that also has the element on which you hooked the event:

```
function fillDiv(e) {
    // Use `e.currentTarget` where you used to use the first argument
}
```

That's handy in case you're using an arrow function or something, where `this` isn't controlled by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. In this case, `i` is your `this`.

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

items.forEach(i => i.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(i) ));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Your approach isn't entirely wrong, but you just can't find you `li` items with a `getElementById("list")` and you're expecting to get a list of items where you want to set the listener, not just one.

Comment: You *can* do that, but there's no reason to and it overcomplicates things. The element on which the event was hooked is available to the handler function in at least two ways already (as `this`, and as `event.currentTarget`); there's no reason to add a third.

Comment: It's a one-liner but yeah, you're right, it can be even more simplified :)

Answer (score 0):

When you add a `p`, you can add an event listener to it, which, when invoked, passes the added `p` as a parameter:

```
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = obj.Name[i];
li.appendChild(p);
p.addEventListener('click', () => fillDiv(p));
```

Or you can use event delegation - add a listener to the container `#list`, and if the clicked target is a `p`, call `fillDiv` with the target:

```
li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('p')) {
    fillDiv(e.target);
  }
});
```